# Worksheets.load("items") fails, leading to an Access Denied error

Tags: typescript, office365, office-js, office-addins

I'm working on an Excel add-in project that was on hold for quite a while. When I stopped working on it, it was working fine, but now I'm getting the following error message:

`AccessDenied: You don't have sufficient permissions for this action.`

By console-logging, I'm able to get the `WorksheetCollection` from `context` and print the object, but when I try to load the items property and then use it, I get the access denied error.

The error object isn't very helpful, but the stack trace points to the office-js library. I'm using a local static version.

Relevant code, `App.tsx`:

```
try {
    var start = +new Date()

    await Excel.run( async context => {
      await this.append_message("Starting")
      var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets
      console.log(sheets)
      sheets.load("items"); await context.sync();

      for ( var i in sheets.items ) {
        let sheet = sheets.items[i]
        ...
        (logic goes here)
        ...
} catch (error) {
    //OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
    OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    await this.append_message("Something went wrong: "+ error)
    console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
  }
```

`manifest.xml` is pretty much the default/sample one with url changes. Permissions are:

```
<Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
```

Excerpts from `Package.json`:

```
 "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --mode development --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --host 0.0.0.0",
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/office-js": "0.0.155",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/webpack": "4.4.22",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "3.1.1",
```

Office version:

```
Microsoft Office 365 Business, Version 1907 (Build 11901.20176 Click-to-Run)
```

OS:

```
 Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, 10.0.17134 Build 17134
```

**EDIT:**

I switched to the CDN version, which didn't solve the problem completely but seems to have changed some things.

Firstly, if I don't load the `items` property, I still can't proceed. Here's the error message:

```
PropertyNotLoaded: The property 'items' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.
```

Secondly, the point where the `AccessDenied` error appears has moved. I haven't been able to figure out where exactly the error is being thrown, but I'm now able to get all sheets and rows.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to load "items" explicitly. Try loading "name" on that line of code and then have `console.log(sheet.name)` where you currently have `(logic goes here)`.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks for trying to help me, Rick. I got the same result when loading and printing the names, an AccessDenied error. When printing `sheets`, items only displays "<Permission denied>"